# DFS with visited times as integer

Tags: python, graph

I have implemented recursive DFS in python where I want to record exploration time for nodes. For e.g

For a graph like this:

[image]

```
idx = 1
def dfs(root, idx):
   if graph[root][1] == 0:
      graph[root][1] = 1
      children = graph[root][0]
      if len(children) == 0:
        graph[root][2] = idx
        return -1
      for val in children:
        if graph[val][1] == 0:
            idx += 1
            if dfs(val, idx) == -1:
                idx += 1
                continue

      graph[root][2] = idx

dfs(1, idx)
print graphs
```

Graph is represented as :

```
graph = {
    1: [[2, 3], 0, 0],
    2: [[4, 5, 6], 0, 0],
    3: [[4,6], 0, 0],
    4: [[5,6], 0, 0],
    5: [[6], 0, 0],
    6: [[], 0, 0]
}
```

First item in values of the dict item is children, second is marked, third is the index when it was done with marking.

The output I get is not correct.

```
{1: [[2, 3], 1, 3], 2: [[4, 5, 6], 1, 3], 3: [[4, 6], 1, 3], 4: [[5, 6], 1, 4], 5: [[6], 1, 6], 6: [[], 1, 5]}
```

5th and 6th explored correctly

Not homework question. I'm practicing implementations.
Correct output is:
Node:idx
1:10, 2:8 , 3:9, 4:7, 5:6, 6:5

Explanation for what the numbers mean:

You start dfs with idx = 1, you can think of the Node 1 started getting explored at idx = 1.

Then we visit Node2 (idx = 2), Node4 -idx = 3, Node 5-idx = 4, then Node 6-idx = 5. 6's discovery time is 5 and cannot be explored further, hence 6's time is 5. We go back to Node 5 whose discovery time was 4 but now the finishing time is 6. 7 for Node 4, 8 for Node et.all

Comment: What would the correct output look like here?

Comment: What do the numbers even mean? What is "10" for node 1? Why are the correct values for node 2 and 3 not the same?

Comment: That image has a ton of white space.

Comment: Your code's indentation is broken. Until you fix it, we can't tell how your code is structured, and it's significantly more difficult to help you.

Comment: @user2357112 Fixed indentation

Answer (score 0):

When a recursive call returns, you have no idea how many nodes it explored. There's a line in your code that increments `idx` by 1 after the recursive call if it found a leaf node, but nothing for the non-leaf case. You need to keep track of the count across function calls, perhaps by returning `idx` as a second return value and updating the caller's value accordingly.

Note that assignments to `idx` in one function call have no effect on the values seen by other calls. `idx` in the `dfs` function is a local variable, and assignments will merely bind a new value to the local copy of the variable.